# Does Kotlin have a network REPL like Clojure's `nrepl`?

Tags: kotlin

Clojure's `nrepl` provide a way to connect to a running remote Clojure program.
Does Kotlin have a network REPL like Clojure's `nrepl`?

Comment: The JVM has hooks to support a wide variety of manipulations and queries on a running program.  This is what debuggers use to connect to and work with a JVM process, either local or remote.  So what I know about are IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse.  Have you thought about using an IDE and a debugging session to do whatever you're looking to do?  Is there some reason that won't work for you?  I don't know if there's something equivalent that works in a REPL sort of mode.  Maybe if we knew more about what you're trying to accomplish, we could offer you more help.

Answer (score 2):

maybe have a look at:

https://github.com/kscripting/kscript#treat-yourself-a-repl-with---interactive

maybe it comes near to what you want to have.

https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript

kscript by Holder Brandl adds enhanced scripting support for Kotlin on *nix-based systems. kscript provides an easy-to-use, very flexible, and almost zero-overhead solution to write self-contained mini-applications with Kotlin.

also available via https://sdkman.io/

```
$ sdk install kscript
```

For trying out small kotlin code snippets, I sometimes just use the `scratches` from my favorite IDE Intellij: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html

Maybe you find the latter also "helpful" for whatever you "intended" to achieve in using a REPL.

Comment: Hi, `kscript` is like the `clj` for `clojure`.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't  - maybe you can define the requirements and what/why you want and someone might develop it

Comment: I personally would't be so quick to state definitively that no REPL-like tool exists to give the OP what they're looking for.  As you say, one could write such a tool.  How can you be so sure that nobody already has?  I chose to instead comment "I don't know of such a tool".

Comment: Because i write a lot of kotlin. Look at my github my 5 pinned repos are kotlin. I have a blog post on how i achieve this (repl) at https://blog.aawadia.dev/2021/04/13/highway-into-service/